# How to see which layout inflation failed?

Tags: java, android, debugging

I get this very generic exception:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Failed to resolve attribute at index 0: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0200a7 a=-1}
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 0: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0200a7 a=-1}
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:816)
    at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:7632)
    at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:7824)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(FrameLayout.java:441)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:372)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:370)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:502)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.getMenuView(ListMenuPresenter.java:102)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase$PanelFeatureState.getListMenuView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:1571)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.initializePanelContent(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:1007)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.openPanel(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:861)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreatePanelView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:487)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelView(ActionBarActivity.java:147)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:661)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:1126)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:299)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21007 SIG: 9
```

There's not a single line of my code in the stack trace, and the exception says on which line is the error, but not in which file(as I have many xml layout files). Is there a reason why this exception is not descriptive enough and what is the best way to debug problems like this one? Thanks!

Comment: the error is happening in your adapter while calling the some layout that i can tell you if you can provide the adapter and the layout i can tell you what is wrong

Comment: Share the xml file please